# Angular2 Google Maps not taking Lat from Object Field

Tags: google-maps, angular

If I assign the value of lat/lng as numbers in the component, this displays a map. If I try to pass a field of a type place object which is defined as a number (place.Lat and place.Lng ) it does not work but the proper values are displayed on the template when I use {{place.Lat}}.
Is this some sort of scope issue ???

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

The error I get for both is

You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

but what you see is all there is, but it displays with lat not with place.Lat . 
Note: all up to date with the latest angular cli install

Comment: Note its contained within a    <div *ngIf="place">, also tried elvis operator but nada

Comment: Well this is very little information to go on, but it clearly looks you have used both latitude and longitude on twice in this template.

Comment: This is all that's on the page.    <div *ngIf="place">
      <row-meta [rowmetadata]="place"></row-meta> 
    <h1>{{ place.Lat }}</h1>
    <sebm-google-map [latitude]="place?.Lat" [longitude]="place?.Lng">
      <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="place?.Lat"    [longitude]="place?.Lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
    </sebm-google-map>
    </div>    The Lat is displayed in the H1 but the map is blank with the above named error

Comment: I am using lazy loading, so I am importing  AgmCoreModule in the appmodule.ts as a forroot(xxxx), then importing it again in the placesmodule.ts with a simple listing in the imports as just"AgmCoreModule" thanks for the help, got me stumped

Comment: If I replace the place object that was returned by the promise with a hard coded object the code works. I still ge the multiple listing error as a silent error but it all works fine, so this is related to data returned by a promise I think.

Comment: Turned out to be simple data type, json was coming in as string.